# Can't write on a file

Tags: python, macos, utf-8

I am trying to write on a file from python on my terminal osX. I know that if the file doesn't exist, the write mode automatically creates a new file. Is that true? Out of the many times I tried it, there was one time that it partially worked. Can anyone tell me if my coding is wrong? Thank you.
Code:

```
with open('mynewfile.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
    a_file.write('these are my new files')
with open('mynewfile.txt', encoding='uff-8')
    print(a_file.read())
```

I can't even get pass the first line with that code. After I put in the first line, I get the invalid syntax error message.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to have that file already? I also typed in the code using a try..except block exactly as my professor has it but it would not do it for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in the third line, missed `as a_file:` and a wrong encoding `uff-8`:

```
>>> with open('mynewfile.txt', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
...     print(a_file.read())
these are my new files
```

> Do I need to have that file already?

You don't need to have the file already as you are creating it.

> I also typed in the code using a try..except block exactly as my
>   professor has it but it would not do it for me either.

You can't use try..except with a syntax error.

Comment: thank you so much. Could you clarify on the error with as a_file:. i'm not understanding that part